# Remove Duplicate Data Based on Three Fields and Two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables that have more than three fields each. There is a group of records that are on both files, the below is a mock example:

Table 1:

`ID  Name   Town     State
 1   Dave   Chicago  IL
 2   Mark   Tea      MD`

Table 2:

`ID  Name  State  Job      Married
 1   Dave  IL     Manager  Yes
 2   Mark  MD     Driver   No`

For my purpose duplicates exist if ID, Name, and State are the same. So the above data are duplicates. How do I delete them from one table (I have over 900 duplicates so deleting one by one is not possible)?

Comment: Is ID not a primary key in both tables?  Why do you need to bother with Name and State?  Or, possibly the other way around: what does the ID have to do with the Name and State?

Comment: ID is not a primary key in either table. ID, Name, and State together is what defines uniqueness. As said above these are mock examples the actual data includes fields for SSN, Effective Date, and Code1 among other fields. The system that is consuming this data allows for any combination of SSNs, Effective Dates, and Code that would create duplicates except for all three together.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete table1
where ID in(select distinct ID from table1  where ID in (Select ID from table2))
```

i dont understand which table has duplicates, if you want to delete duplicate data from one table1 then you can use this query

Answer (score 0):

This query will produce a de-duplicated result set:

```
SELECT Table1.ID,
    Table1.NAME,
    Table1.Town,
    Table1.STATE,
    NULL AS Job,
    NULL AS Married
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT Table1.ID
        FROM Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table2.STATE = Table1.STATE)
        AND (Table2.NAME = Table1.NAME)
        AND (Table1.ID = Table2.ID)
        )

UNION

SELECT Table2.ID,
    Table2.NAME,
    NULL AS Town,
    Table2.STATE,
    Table2.Job,
    Table2.Married
FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward way to do it, assuming that you want to delete from Table1.  I'm a little rusty with Access SQL syntax, but I believe this works:

```
DELETE FROM [Table1]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Table2]
    WHERE [Table2].[ID]      = [Table1].[ID]
        AND [Table2].[Name]  = [Table1].[Name]
        AND [Table2].[State] = [Table1].[State]
)
```

Comment: I started running this query but it is still processing after more than 30 minutes and doesn't look like it is close to done. I am querying off of a few thousand records in table2 and about 450 thousand in table1, all of which is saved directly in access. Do you know if there's something wrong with the query or is it too much data for access to handle for this particular query?

Comment: @Cameron I'd try creating a multi-field index on ID, Name, and State for both tables.  That should improve performance.  When you're done removing duplicates, you can remove the index if this was a one-time operation.